# Why do I get a CMake Error in gmock's CMakeLists.txt when compiling gtest dependency?

Tags: unit-testing, cmake, googletest

I'm using GCC 4.8.4, GNU Make 3.81, and CMake 2.8.12.2 on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine trying to compile a small project that depends on gtest and gmock. You can view the full source of this project along with my CMake files [here](https://github.com/natemurthy/misc/tree/master/cpp-stuff/containers). I perform the usual steps of doing `mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. && make` but hit this error after downloading, extracting, and configuring the gmock 1.7.0 dependency:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:51 (add_subdirectory):
  add_subdirectory given source "../gtest" which is not an existing
  directory.

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:56 (config_compiler_and_linker):
  Unknown CMake command "config_compiler_and_linker".
```

To be clear, these are errors found when running the `add_subdirectory` and `config_compiler_and_linker` commands in gmock's [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/google/googlemock/blob/master/googlemock/CMakeLists.txt) file when attempting to reference the gtest dependency. I've raised this issue on [Google's github account](https://github.com/google/googlemock/issues/203) already to see if any contributors could help me out.

Here's another example of the same build failure, not sure how the owners of this project resolved their issue: https://travis-ci.org/open-eid/esteid-pkcs11/builds/39580725

Comment: GMock works with gtest (this is explicitely noted in the README). You should have gtest sources downloaded into `gtest` directory within gmock source directory, or in the upper directory. The error means that you **haven't placed gtest** properly.

Comment: I have `gtest` in my dependencies (see https://github.com/natemurthy/misc/blob/master/cpp-stuff/containers/test/CMakeLists.txt). What's the proper way to place it?

Comment: According to the [source code](https://github.com/google/googlemock/blob/master/googlemock/CMakeLists.txt#L15), assuming you have `googlemock/CMakeLists.txt`, you should have either `gtest/CMakeLists.txt` or `googlemock/gtest/CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: That's exactly what I have in my `build/test` folder after running `cmake`: `build/test/gtest` and `build/test/gmock`

Comment: According to your `CMakeLists.txt`, you have `build/test/*gtest*/src/*gtest*/CMakeLists.txt` and `build/test/*gmock*/src/*gmock*/CMakeLists.txt`, which is different from gmock expectations. Note, that for [ExternalProject_Add()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/ExternalProject.html) *PREFIX* is **not the same** as source directory. You may use same *PREFIX* for both gtest and gmock. Also, do not forget about dependency between these targets.

Comment: What do you suggest I replace `PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/gtest` and `PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/gmock` with in my calls to `ExternalProject_Add()` so that I have the expected build directory structure?

Comment: E.g. you may use `PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/3dparty` for both gmock and gtest.

Comment: I tried exactly as you suggested, but now I get this error https://pastebin.com/Ukk987Bz

Comment: You may check content of *PREFIX* directories for gmock and gtest, and adjust *PREFIX* options for achive proper layout. I have described this layout in my second comment.

Answer (score 0):

This project has been absorbed into the [GoogleTest (http://github.com/google/googletest) project. All open googlemock issues have been moved there.

1) Download googleTest, 
2) unzip googletest, 
3) Enter googleMock folder, 
4) cd build-aux, 
5) cmake ..,
done